# Should the photo in CV be attached with a paperclip or inserted electronically?

Tags: resume, france

In French culture, should the photo (passport size photo) in a CV be attached using a paperclip or be scanned and inserted electronically (via Word for example) and then print the CV in color?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you include a photo in your curriculum vitae (it is not required), you should definitely insert it directly in your document.

Answer (score 2):

It would look very old fashion to do so and it could get lost in the recruiting process.

That said, doing such thing will make your CV stands out (for being odd and old fashion) and I could imagine somebody in design or artistic field doing such thing on purpose.

So, except if you absolutely know what you are going with this: insert your picture electronically!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it has much to do with culture. Both are accepted. It only depends if you know or not how to insert a picture in your document. Obviously electronic insertion in better and will make everybody's life easier. So unless your asked to because your photo might be used later separately go for the digital one...